# Getting the second record where the sql query is satisfied

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to fill my list box with  the task names from the database where the priority is equal to an item in my `List<object>`.

The code below populates the list box, but the error is that in my database I have two records with the priority of 1 and so it only finds the first record and outputs that twice. In attempt to fix a previous error which was that it displayed the two records twice, I added the `break;` which now only makes it show the first record that satisfies the sql query.

I am doing it like this because the user has the option to sort in order of priority, so I get all the priority values and store them in a `List<object>`, sort them via a bubble sort implementation, and then do the code below to output them back to the list box in the order that the user wants.

So my question is, How can I output all of the records from my database correctly?

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    string sql = "SELECT [Task Name] FROM Tasks WHERE Priority = " + Convert.ToInt32(list[i].GetValue(0));
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        using (OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            List<object[]> taskNameList = new List<object[]>();

            if (dataReader.HasRows) //if the table isnt empty
            {
                while (dataReader.Read()) //loop to the end of the database
                {
                    object[] tasks = new object[dataReader.FieldCount]; //object array of same length as the amount of task names in database
                    taskNameList.Add(tasks);
                    for (int j = 0; j <= dataReader.FieldCount - 1; j++)
                    {
                        tasks[j] = dataReader[j]; //fill object array with task names
                    }
                    taskList.Items.AddRange(tasks); //add to list box
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the exact Query you are using? I feel that the Query you are using is the one to blame.

Comment: @PaulFrancis Yes I am, why what's wrong with it?

Comment: Based on your problem, I just thought the Query could return something than what you expect to see. However, if you are using the exact same query then you might need to do some debugging and see where it is going wrong.

Comment: @PaulFrancis in that case, the sql is fine, I've debugged it and the only reason why it's going wrong is because I've got two values in my database that satisfy the query but I want to display one at a time, because without the break; it loops over both if them and displays them both twice, and with the break; it only displays the first record twice whereas I want it to show the first record then the second record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by putting an if statement inside the while loop to test if the list box already contained the task name before I added it to the list box. The code below is as follows:

```
  while (dataReader.Read()) //loop to the end of the database
  {
        if (taskList.Items.Contains(dataReader[0]) == false)  //so that it doesn't duplicate records in the list box that satisfy the priority value
        {
            object[] tasks = new object[dataReader.FieldCount]; //object array of same length as the amount of task names in database
            taskNameList.Add(tasks);
            for (int j = 0; j <= dataReader.FieldCount - 1; j++)
            {
                tasks[j] = dataReader[j]; //fill object array with task names
            }
            taskList.Items.AddRange(tasks); //add to list box

        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid returning the same name twice you can add `Distinct` to your query.

Also, because you are only returning one column, you should be able to simply the code further to something like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    string sql = "SELECT Distinct [Task Name] FROM Tasks WHERE Priority = " + Convert.ToInt32(list[i].GetValue(0));
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
    using (OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())  
            taskList.Items.Add((string) dataReader[0]); 
    }
}
```